# Surrounding a specific HTML tag with another HTML tag using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Is there any way in XSLT by which we can transform an HTML file to surround an existing HTML tag(in this scenario "img") with another HTML tag(in this scenario "center") without rewriting the entire HTML structure again in XSLT?

Existing HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
         <img id="image" width: 747px; height: 1056px" src="image.jpg"/>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

After transformation using XSLT, expected output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
         <center>
              <img id="image" width: 747px; height: 1056px" src="image.jpg"/>  
         </center>
     <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I thought of doing it through XSLT identity transformation but I am not getting how to surround only specific HTML tag(in this case "img") with another HTML tag

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note: Through XSLT, I do not want to rewrite the entire structure of the expected HTML output again(if possible). I just want the `<center>` HTML tag to be added around the `<img>` HTML tag.

Comment: This is rather trivial: add another template matching `img` and add the wrapper there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `xsl:copy-of` instruction

```
<xsl:template match="img">
    <center>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </center>
</xsl:template>
```